# argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Here is the trigger function i made. What i want to do here is, if there is a change in the test_tx_out table, the trigger function is triggered. a variable is declared boolean which stores true or false. then, i check whether there already exist the address in test_address table using `select exists(...)` query and store it inside boolAddress. And the if condition is if `new.stake_address_id AND boolAddress` is true, then the inside statements is executed, else the other else block of statement is executed, but i get the error `argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer in postgresql`. How do i convert new.stake_address_id into boolean? Well, i thought if `new.stake_address_id` is not empty or null, it will be true. Basically, i want new.stake_address_id as true if there is a value and false if not.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_stake_addresses_tx_out_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    boolAddress BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    select exists (SELECT 1 FROM test_address where address = new.address) into boolAddress;
    IF new.stake_address_id AND boolAddress THEN
        UPDATE test_address
        SET amount = amount + new.value
        WHERE NEW.stake_address_id = test_address.id;
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO test_address(id,address,amount)
        VALUES(new.stake_address_id,new.address,new.value);
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
end;
$$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER test1
    AFTER INSERT
    ON "test_tx_out"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_stake_addresses_tx_out_trigger();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well, i thought if new.stake_address_id is not empty or null,

An integer value is not a boolean (and it can only be null, there is no such thing as an "empty" ingeger)

If you want a boolean expression with an integer, you need to compare it to something. If you want to test if it's not null, use `is not null`

```
if new.stake_address_id is not null and boolAddress then
```